# How to get filename of xlsx file with apache poi XSSF?

Tags: java, apache, scala, scala-2.10, xssf

How to get filename of xlsx file with apache poi XSSF?

```
case class XlsxSplitter(path: InputStream){

  lazy val spreadSheet=load(path)

  def load(path: InputStream):SpreadSheet={
    val wb = new XSSFWorkbook(path)
    .........
  }
}
```

I could extract it from the path, but I would like to make my case class as generic as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to change the path attribute to a attribute of type `File` instead of `InputStream`, you can get the filename from the file itself by `file.getName();`

Otherwise I think you have no other choice than extracting it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can get file name by using method `file.getOriginalFilename()`